# MySql Database Orientation

Tags: mysql, sql, resources, windows-server-2003, recordset

I have a database that has over 118 columns and only 6 rows, below is an extract from the table.

[image: MySql Table]

What is the best way to go about re-orientate the table so that it isn't as resource heavy as it is at the moment, (A windows Server 2003 is struggling now that the table is expanding)

To get the records we select everything with the language that we want

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_language WHERE lang = en
```

Then use the record sets within the HTML tables to output the right cell that we require.

Is it better to keep it in this orientation and only select the colums I need or to redesign the whole table.

Thanks,
07lodgeT

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how 6 rows can be "resource intensive" regardless if you have 118 columns or not, but that is an other matter.

For your question, you might consider pivoting the whole thing. Something like

**term lang translation**

site_name     en     Just stainless

site_name     es     Solo Inox

...

part_no    en    Part No

part_no    es    Cordigo
...

(Sorry for the poor table formatting)

To get the at particular rows you would query it with e.g.

```
SELECT translation FROM tbl_language WHERE lang = 'en' AND term = 'site_name'
```